# non blocking info dialog in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a simple info box to display some status output, that I would alternatively dump to the console using `print`. The easiest possibility that I found is the following:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

from tkMessageBox import showinfo    
showinfo('some caption', 'some info')
```

The only problem with this implementation is that my program (**not written in Tkinter**) will not continue running, until the 'ok' button of the `showinfo` messagebox is pressed. That is, the `showinfo` dialog will block.

**Therefore my question:** Is there a simple way to make `showinfo` non-blocking? Are there alternative messagebox implementations in Tkinter that are non-blocking? I can think of the typical use-cage of showing a help page - the window should open and the main program keeps on running normally.

**EDIT1:** here's a simple help window that I came up with, but unfortunately it doesn't show up, unless I launch a different `tkMessageBox` or a similar object:

```
class TextInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, window_title = 'window', textfield = 'a text field', label = None):

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.window_title = window_title
        self.textfield = textfield

        # set window title
        if window_title:
            self.top.title(window_title)

        # add label if given
        if label:
            tk.Label(self.top, text=window_title).grid(row=0)

        # create the text field
        self.textField = tk.Text(self.top, width=80, height=20, wrap=tk.NONE)
        if textfield:
            self.textField.insert(1.0, textfield)
        self.textField.grid(row=1)

        # create the ok button
        b = tk.Button(self.top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.grid(row=2)

    def ok(self):
        self.top.destroy()
```

And this is how I call the window:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
TextInfo(self.root, window_title, textfield, label)  
# don't call root.mainloop() here, because this will lead to blocking.
```

Is there some kind of property or event that I need to set for the window to show up? If I call `root.mainloop()` the window will show up, but then my GUI is blocked again.

Comment: Dialog (and the derived DialogBox) does a non configurable global grab in its Show method so no, other than sub-classing and using a substitute Show method, you can't make Dialog non-blocking. 

see http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=836513 for a perl implementation

Comment: @JoranBeasley so there is not `help page` kind of dialog in Tkinter that would just pop up and sit there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the tkMessageBox as it doesn't allow much configuration. Just create your own custom dialog that looks like one. This [page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) talks a lot about creating custom Tkinter dialogs.

Comment: thanks! I've put together some code, unfortunately it only works when I run it on the console - not through my GUI. Somehow my Tkinter dialog only shows up, if I start a 'proper' tkinter window. Any clue what's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: You probably need to have the proper GUI running in the background. I think you can hide the main GUI while you show the dialog and then Show it again. This link shows one way to do it: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/243559/need-help-tkinter-hide-window-then-show

Comment: I don't use Tkinter as my main GUI. Your solution doesn't work :(

Comment: Just launch the Tkinter part of the app in a different thread or use subprocess then.