# Tkinter equivalent of non-blocking System.Windows.Forms.Form.Show() from .NET

Tags: python, .net, user-interface, tkinter

(This question was [originally posted](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-October/003505.html) to python-tkinter mailing list)

I'm trying to replicate a non-blocking (or modeless) window behaviour from a Windows .NET application using Tkinter.

The application I've got shows a new window in response to some event (might be non-GUI event) and the execution continues leaving the new window displayed.

Here is the relevant code:

```
private void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 f = new Form1();
   f.Show(); // displays a window and continues
   Console.WriteLine("Form created");
}
```

The important bit is call to the [Show() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) of .NET class `System.Windows.Forms.Form/Control`.

The `foo()` function may be called from a non-GUI application, as response to some signal or even invoked from a C++ application.

The point is there is no explicit waiting for events and the window is modeless.

How can I achieve similar behaviour in Tkinter?
Is there any Tkinter idiomatic way to avoid calling `mainloop()` or `wait_window()` methods (which both are blocking)?

Comment: probably related: [non blocking info dialog in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418625/non-blocking-info-dialog-in-tkinter)

Comment: @DominicKexel Yes, it seems the question you found is very similar, so related. I didn't find it earlier. My question though gives important .NET reference to example of desired behaviour. It might be helpful to those who aim to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a non-modal popup window by creating an instance of `Toplevel` (assuming you've already created the root window). However, you need to have the event loop running because that is the mechanism tkinter uses to know when the window needs to be repainted.

Comment: I see, so it looks Tkinter root window is required as the Tkinter event loop is anyway. Is that correct conclusion drawn from your answer?

Comment: @mloskot: Yes, a root window is required, if you aren't using it for anything else, you can use it for your dialog instead of creating a toplevel. And, yes, the event loop must be running for the dialog to respond to events.