# Can´t move object when I add messagebox

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I had a program when I could move with a word thing, but when I add message box it stopped working. How to fix it?

This is my program:

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

canvas = Canvas(width=1920, height=1080)
canvas.pack()




from tkinter import messagebox

dialog_title = '?????????????'
dialog_text = 'Question?'
answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text)

if answer == 'yes':
    canvas.create_text(960,300,text="yes",font="Arial 50",fill="Blue")
else:  # 'no'
    canvas.create_text(960,300,text="no",font="Arial 50",fill="Blue")


y=canvas.create_text(1000,500, text="thing",font="Arial 30",fill="pink")

def r (event):
    canvas.move(y,15,0)

def l (event):
    canvas.move(y,-15,0)

def d (event):
    canvas.move(y,0,15)

def u (event):
    canvas.move(y,0,-15)



canvas.bind_all('<Right>',r)
canvas.bind_all('<Left>',l)
canvas.bind_all('<Down>',d)
canvas.bind_all('<Up>',u)




o=randrange(100,1800,15)
p=randrange(100,980,15)
i=canvas.create_text(o,p,text="end",fill="red",font="Arial 50")
```

Comment: The messagebox is a modal dialog, which means it grabs the input focus  until it is destroyed. A way around this is to not use the messagebox, and create your own (non-modal) dialog that pops up a message, but doesn't take the input focus away. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418625/non-blocking-info-dialog-in-tkinter) confronts a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The messagebox is specifically designed to block any other operations until you close it. The term for this is *modal dialog* where *modal* refers to the fact that you enter a limited *mode* until the dialog is closed.

If you want to display information in another window, you can create an instance of `Toplevel` and then add any other widgets you want. This new window is not modal (unless you explicitly make it so).